# Request Animation Frame issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I've been writing some examples with RequestAnimationFrame and Canvas:

```
var ctx;
var x=0,y=0,v_x=5,v_y=5;
window.addEventListener('load',init);
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(f){
        window.setTimeout(f,1000/60);
    }
})();
function init(){
    ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    draw();
}
function draw(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,50,50);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    x += v_x;
    y += v_y;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

The problem is that I want the Rect() to go diagonally down with the variables v_x and v_y and the requestAnimationFrame, then I get the Rectangle fully drawn, but it doesn't move!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to set the position of the rectange to be `x` and `y` other than `0,0`. So change this `ctx.rect(0,0,50,50)`, to this `ctx.rect(x,y,50,50)`. Along with that you will want to clear the canvas before you redraw:

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);   // Clears the canvas 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x,y,50,50);               // Sets the rects pos to be x,y
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    x += v_x;
    y += v_y;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1wossge/)